# osmdroid - Add an area to the map

Tags: android, dictionary, coordinates, openstreetmap, area

I want to show touristic areas of Morocco in an osmdroid map in my Android application.

First of all, I've been searching the web for ways to get a list of coordinates (longitude & latitude) that can define an area (like an array or json), but with no luck. There are solutions for only one point on the map.

Secondly, with these coordinates, how can I show an area on osmdroid ? Thanks.

Comment: I have one question. I also want to use `osmdroid` for maps, would it need Google Play Services to start maps or I can get rid of it and use maps without being dependent on the Google Play Services? Please Reply. I want to use osmdroid because I don't want to be dependent on Google Play Services.

Comment: @Apurva You don't have to use anything Google related. Just OSMDroid will do it

Comment: Would you say how can I integrate `osmdroid` or `osmbonuspack` in android studio? Give me any link you have used. I read it's documentation but it's not clear which `.jar` files are to be copied in `libs` folder and I could not find the modification of `build.gradle` file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First I would highly recommend you to use Google Maps Api V2 through the Google Play Services. This will work much easier. Any reason why you are not using this ?

Second, to draw a polygon on the map do soemthing like

```
private void AddPolygon() {
    int diff=1000;

    GeoPoint pt1=new GeoPoint(13.002798, 77.580000);
    GeoPoint pt2= new GeoPoint(pt1.getLatitudeE6()+diff, pt1.getLongitudeE6());
    GeoPoint pt3= new GeoPoint(pt1.getLatitudeE6()+diff, pt1.getLongitudeE6()+diff);
    GeoPoint pt4= new GeoPoint(pt1.getLatitudeE6(), pt1.getLongitudeE6()+diff);
    GeoPoint pt5= new GeoPoint(pt1);


    PathOverlay myOverlay= new PathOverlay(Color.RED, this);
    myOverlay.getPaint().setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);

    myOverlay.addPoint(pt1);
    myOverlay.addPoint(pt2);
    myOverlay.addPoint(pt3);
    myOverlay.addPoint(pt4);
    myOverlay.addPoint(pt5);

    map.getOverlays().add(myOverlay);
}
```

Comment: We are a company that has her own GIS, that's why we use custom map apis, because that's the only way to show our own tiles.  
The code is working perfectly, but the is that I will be having dozens of points to define an area, I actually have a KML file of every area I want to show, is there any way to give osmdroid the KML and show it automatically ?

Comment: Google Maps V2 has introduced TileProvider and TileOverlay to be able to display your own tiles.

Comment: Also note that the code I have given in my first answer is actually for use with osmdroid.

Maybe that was unclear from that post (and you where thinking that is GoogleMaps code, but it is not, it is osmdroid code).

Comment: @Knarf: It would have been useful to see an actual image of how that polygon would have looked like.